# Definition for "seeded bread"

Tags: word-meaning, image-identification, food

I'd like to add an English definition for "seeded bread" on one of my Anki flashcards. I've looked on the sites of the major monolingual dictionaries, but couldn't find anything. I'm not quite sure if the simple definition I had in mind would suffice.

The bread I had in mind is the one seen here:
[image]

Comment: This might work better if you had a picture of what you had in mind in particular. There are a few different ways to combine seeds and bread.

Comment: The vagueness of what is a seeded bread was indeed complicating things. I'll edit my post.

Comment: "bread with seeds mixed into the dough and/or sprinkled onto it before baking"

Comment: That one sounds good to me. I wouldn't have been able to write this myself. Thanks!

Comment: I'd call that "granary bread" but that may just be a Britishism, and is probably a trademark.

Comment: Actually, I have "granary bread" as a separate card, and the Oxford Dictionary indeed lists it as a trademark (Wiktionary defines it as "Bread, not made from white or brown flour, that contains wheatgerm and whole grains.").

Answer (score 1):

In general you can define it something like this.

> Seeded bread, also known as seed bread, seeded dough and seed dough:
>   Bread containing edible plant seeds.

And if you want to be more specific, [Tᴚoɯɐuo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10264/t%E1%B4%9Ao%C9%AF%C9%90uo)'s [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127963/definition-for-seeded-bread#comment257881_127963) is a great addition, although I'd say *"edible plant seeds"* instead of just *"seeds"* there, too.

> Seeded bread, also known as seed bread, seeded dough and seed dough:
>   Bread with edible plant seeds mixed into the dough and/or sprinkled onto it before baking.

Comment: I was looking for a definition that doesn't sound trivial and overly succinct, that's why the more specific definition in the comment appealed to me. Thankfully I don't have to press the text into the memory of a Commodore 64.